# construct a exchangeable random sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are arbitary real numbers. How to construct a sequence $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ from $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ so that $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ are exchangeable?

Comment: What does exchangeable mean in this context?

Comment: Just let $Y_n$ be iid samples from some distribution on $\{X_i:i\ge 1\}$.

Comment: How to define the distribution on $X_i$? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Like, let $N(1),N(2),\dots$ be iid geometric variables, and let $Y_i=X_{N(i)}$.